# Module not appearing in dependency list

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

For starters, let me state that I have been working with modules and dependencies for a while, and this is an error report, not a "how do I".

I have my project structure separated in several different modules, one containing the core features, one UI module and several libraries.

The project structure is like

```
Project
\settings.gradle
\Module1
\\build.gradle
\Module2
\\build.gradle
\Module3
\\build.gradle
\Module4
\\build.gradle
\Module5
\\build.gradle
```

Now, code-wise I have a settings.gradle

```
include ':Module1', ':Module2', ':Module3', ':Module4', ':Module5'
```

Module2 depends on modules 3-5 so its build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Module3')
    compile project(':Module4')
    compile project(':Module5')
}
```

Modules 3-5 are `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

Module1 is the app itself, and its build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies {
    compile project(':Module2')
}
```

Now, my problem:

Module1 is not bringing Module2, and Android Studio doesn't even acknowledge its existence. I can refresh build.gradle and assemble it along with its dependencies without issue, but Module1 is not able to.

When coming to the code, none of the imports is resolved.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and how did you solve it?

Comment: I do not understand your problem in detail. which build.gradle do you mean that does work? And please let me know it you are able to build your project from command line. If this works it is just a configuration problem of android studio.

Comment: There was an answer before that was deleted, I've singled out the problem to an error happening silently in the library preventing it from building.